# Golang Multiple Channel Write/Receive Ordering

Tags: go

My specific issue is that I have an unbuffered channel and am spawning multiple goroutines bounded with a semaphore to perform work:

```
func main() {
    sem := make(chan struct{}, 10) // allow ten concurrent parsers
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    DoSomething("http://example.com", sem, wg)

    wg.Wait()
    // all done
}

func DoSomething(u string, sem chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    sem <- struct{}{}        // grab
    defer func() { <-sem }() // release


    var newSomethings []string

    // ...

    for u := range newSomethings {
        wg.Add(1)
        go DoSomething(u)
    }
}
```

If there are multiple `DoSomething` goroutines on the stack, blocked on the `sem` write (or inversely on a read) When a write happens is there any ordering to which go routine gets through with the write?? I would guess it were random but I could imagine:

- it is random
- writes/receives happen in the order they are registered
- implementation dependent

I looked at a couple of resources and was unable to find a solution:

- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/247
- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator
- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types

I'm wondering if this is undefined and/or implementation dependent, or if this logic is located and defined somewhere within go core?

Comment: I don't think it's specified, but you can see the implementation in `runtime/chan.go`, senders and receivers are queued in a linked list. Servicing the senders in order is logical, but the order that your goroutines are queued up is almost always non-deterministic, so reasoning about this isn't usually useful. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Asking this question at all is somewhat worrisome - code should not depend on the order of execution of concurrent operations. If the order of operation is important, the code should be synchronized.

Comment: awesome @JimB I would be happy to accept your comment as an answer if you feel like posting it? I couldn't imagine a better answer! it's exactly what i was wondering, thank you

Comment: I played around with this a while back, it may be of interest to you: https://github.com/lytics/toolbucket/tree/master/orderedtask  I don't maintain it, so take it as an example only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order that goroutines blocked on a send operation are serviced is not defined, but it's implemented as a FIFO. You can see the implementation in [runtime/chan.go](https://golang.org/src/runtime/chan.go), which uses a linked list to track the channel's senders and receivers.

We can try to make an example showing the effective ordering like so:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ready := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        i := i
        go func() {
            ready <- 1
            ch <- i
        }()
        <-ready
        runtime.Gosched()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        v := <-ch
        if i != v {
            panic("out of order!")
        }
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/u0ukR-5Ptw4

This still isn't technically correct, because there's no way to observe blocking on a send operation, so there's still a race between the `ready` send and the send to `ch` on the next line. We can try to eliminate that with the `runtime.Gosched` call here, or even a `time.Sleep`, but without explicit synchronization there's no guarantee of a ["happens before"](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_2) relationship.

Regardless, this queues up the goroutines and shows the expected output order, and if they weren't queued up already, it would be more likely to process the values out of order.

You can see by this example that we can't truly determine the order that the goroutines are queued up, it is almost always non-deterministic, and therefore reasoning about this isn't usually useful in practice.